# What is Object[] and Object o in java

Tags: java, collections

I found this example,one of java book.i run this code into eclipse.but cannot understand some things.will u be able to understand me?

```
import java.util.*;

class Dog {
    public String name;
    Dog(String n) {
        name = n;
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
class ItTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Dog> d = new ArrayList<Dog>();
        Dog dog = new Dog("Kutta");
        d.add(dog);
        d.add(new Dog("Kheki Kutta"));
        d.add(new Dog("Leri Kutta"));
        Iterator<Dog> i3 = d.iterator(); 
        while (i3.hasNext()) {
            Dog d2 = i3.next(); 
            System.out.println(d2.name);
        }
        System.out.println("size " + d.size());
        System.out.println("get1 " + d.get(1).name);
        System.out.println("Kutta " + d.indexOf(dog));
        d.remove(2);
        Object[] oa = d.toArray();
        for(Object o : oa) {
            Dog d2 = (Dog)o;
            System.out.println("oa " + d2.name);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens in these lines

```
Object[] oa = d.toArray();
for(Object o : oa) {
    Dog d2 = (Dog)o;
    System.out.println("oa " + d2.name);
```

What is `Object[] oa` and what is `Object o` also?

Comment: Any Java tutorial will easily explain: java.lang.Object is the root Java object class; Object [] is an array of references of type Object.  Please read more on your own.  This question is too basic.

Comment: each of these lines is either documented pretty well, or there exist tons of resources about it. the only reason why i don't vote to close this question is that theres no option "user is too lazy to do basic research"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author ought to be able to answer this for themselves with a minimum of reading and effort.

Comment: @Paul you can write your own reason to vote to close.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza oh, yeah right. i forget about that from time to time

Answer (score 2):

`Object[] oa` is an array of objects, is the result of calling [`List#toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--).

This part of the code:

```
for (Object o : oa) {
    /* your code goes here */
}
```

Is called [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with). It's like writing this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oa.length; i++) {
    Object o = oa[i];
    /* your code goes here */
}
```

Where `Object o` is a local variable to obtain an element in the array. [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) is the root class in Java.

Please, for future times, if there's code you don't understand, then you should first search about it on [the official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)